# How can I figure the definitions of C macro expressions in the following assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm having so much difficulty with a question I was assigned for homework.  I have the following C code and the subsequent assembly:

```
int foo(int n, int A[X(n)][Y(n)], int j){
    int i;
    int result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < X(n); i++)
        result += A[i][j];
    return result;
}

movl    8(%ebp), %eax
leal    (%eax,%eax), %edx
leal    (%edx,%eax), %ecx
movl    %edx, %ebx
leal    1(%edx), %eax
movl    $0, %edx
testl   %eax, %eax
jle     .L3
leal    0(,%ecx,4), %esi
movl    16(%ebp), %edx
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
leal    (%ecx,%edx,4), %eax
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $1, %ecx
addl    $2, %ebx
.L4:
addl    (%eax), %edx
addl    $1, %ecx
addl    %esi, %eax  
cmpl    %ebx, %ecx
jne     .L4
.L3:
movl    %edx, %eax
```

I need to find out the definitions of X and Y.  I believe that n is initially stored in **eax**, and then 2n is stored in **edx** and 3n in **ecx**. So I think esi would equal 3n * 4.  Also, because *result* is initially stored as **movl    $0, %edx** and the following lines are incremented by one I'm thinking that X would be equal to **#define X(n + 1)**.  Also, I believe **addl  %esi, %eax** would be Y. So since **esi = %ecx * 4** does Y = 4n?  However, this is where I begin to get severely confused.  Thank's all.

Answer (score 1):

Cute exercise.

The declaration seems to define *A* as a C99 variable-length-array. Incidentally these have exceedingly poor compiler support and are optional in C11.

The inner Y(n) dimension may then be inferred from the array stride across loop iterations, where *EAX* is the pointer and *ESI* the pitch, and appears to be defined as n*3. As for X(n) we may infer it from the loop entry condition when i = 0, and it appears to expand as N*2+1.

```
#define X(n) ((n)*2+1) 
#define Y(n) ((n)*3)
```

Annotated assembly:

```
_foo:
    ;Prologue (assumed)
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    ;Pre-scale N
    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    lea edx,[eax+eax]
    lea ecx,[edx+eax]   ;ECX = N*3
    mov ebx,edx         ;EBX = N*2

    ;Bail out earily if X(n) <= 0
    lea eax,[edx+1]     ;EAX = N*2+1
    mov edx,0
    test eax,eax        ;(OF=0)
    jle @@end           ;Proceed if N*2+1 > 0

    ;Prepare loop counters
    lea esi,[ecx*4]     ;ESI = N*3*sizeof int, array stride
    mov edx,[ebp+16]    ;EDX = j
    mov ecx,[ebp+12]
    lea eax,[ecx+edx*4] ;EAX = &A[0][j]

    mov edx,0           ;EDX = 0, accumulator
    mov ecx,1           ;ECX = 1, loop counter
    add ebx,2           ;EBX = N*2+2

    ;Step through the loop
@@loop:
    add edx,[eax]       ;EDX += A[i][j]
    add ecx,1           ;Increment loop counter
    add eax,esi         ;++A
    cmp ecx,ebx
    jne @@loop          ;[1..N*2+2) <=> [0..N*2+1)

@@end:
    ;Epilogue
    mov eax,edx         ;Return the sum
    pop ebp
    ret
```